# Open multiple files and store them in array of structures

Tags: c, file-io

I need some help with my task. I have to open unknown number of files and store them in data structure at the **start of program**.
 First file contains names of two other files and so on ( this is explained more under example of first file).
Each file has same structure:

> [Title of file]
>  [name of file X]
> [name of file Y]
> [Text]

, for **example**,  **first file** will looks like this:

`File 1`
 `file_8.txt`
  `file_25.txt`
`Text: "this is some example text, lenght is unknown so`
 `so i will have to use  malloc and realloc to`
 `dynamicaly store it."`



The name of first file  is typed in stdin by user when starting a program 

(example:  `./task1 page_1.txt`)

> The first line stores the title of the file. 
> The second and third lines each contain a file name of a next file that i have to read/store.If there are no further names of files on 2nd and 3rd line, both of the lines will have " **-\n** ".
>  Text starts at fourth line (can have multiple lines like in example above)

My **struct** for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char title[1000];    // should use malloc and realloc and not this way
    char file_x[1000];  // dynamically
    char file_y[1000];  // dynamically
    char text[10000]; 

} Story;
```

My **main** looks like this:

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char c[100];
    char buffer[100];
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Story *temp = (Story*) malloc(sizeof(Story) * 8);
if(input)
{
    int flag = 0;
    while (fgets(c, sizeof(buffer),input) != NULL)      
    {
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            sscanf(c, "%s", temp->title);
        }       
        else if(flag == 1)
        {
            sscanf(c, "%s", temp->file_x);
        }
        else if(flag == 2)
        {
            sscanf(c, "%s", temp->file_y);
        }
        else
        {
            while(!feof(input))
            {
                fread(temp->text, sizeof(Story),1,input);
            }
        }
        flag++;
    }
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", temp->title,
    temp->file_x, temp->file_y);
}
else if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR MESSAGE HERE \n");
    return 1;
}
free(temp);
fclose(input);
return 0;
```

}

For now i managed to open first file and store it to structure. I need an idea how to open and store all other files and also have to implement it using dynamic memory allocation. 
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are minimizing the size of each struct `story`, then you can allocate for the filenames, otherwise the standard macro `PATH_MAX` will provide sufficient storage for each (4096 bytes generally). If you don't have many, don't worry about dynamically allocating storage for the filenames, just for the `text` of each file. No need to dynamically allocate `temp`, just `story temp = { .title = "" );` will declare `temp` on the stack and initialize all bytes zero. If you declare `char *text;`, then you can dynamically allocate for `text`.

Comment: How will you know when you have reached the last file? Will the last file *line 3* be blank?

Comment: The second and third lines each contain a file name of a next file that i have to read/store.If there are no further names of files on 2nd and 3rd line, both of the lines will have " -\n ".    example:  TITLE:`title 25 ` SECOND LINE`:  - ` THIRD LINE: `-`   FOURTH LINE: ` text:" This is the end, last file ... "`

Comment: Makes sense. I'll drop an example in a few minutes.

Comment: thank you for your time , i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your lesson is covering recursion as with each element in your array of `story` you will need to branch an unknown number of times to read `file_x` and `file_y` (each of which can contain additional `file_x` and `file_y` within). Your procedural option is to follow down the trail of all `file_x` and then return to each `file_y` repeating the process until you reach the final files in each chain where `file_x` and `file_y` are empty.

Before determining which approach you will take, you simply need a way to read one file, extract the `title`, `file_x`, `file_y` and allocate and store `text`. This is a fairly straight-forward process where your primary task is to ***validate each step*** so you have confidence that you are processing *actual data* and are not invoking *Undefined Behavior* by reading from a file that isn't actually open or attempting to write (or read) beyond the bounds of your storage.

Here is a short example that takes a pointer to `story` to fill and the `filename` to read from. You will note a repetitive process involved. (read the string with `fgets`, get the length, validate the last char read was `'\n'` indicating you read the whole line, and finally trimming the `'\n'` by either overwriting with a *nul-terminating* character so you don't have newlines dangling off the end of your stored string, or overwriting with a `' '` (space) in the case of `text` where you are concatenating lines together.

**note:** below, `realloc` is never called directly on the pointer to `text`. Instead a `tmp` pointer is used with `realloc` to validate `realloc` succeeds before assigning the new block to `text`. (otherwise you will lose your pointer to `text` if `realloc` fails -- because it returns `NULL`)

```
/* read values into struct story 's' from 'filename' */
int read_file (story *s, char *filename)
{
    size_t len = 0,                 /* var for strlen */
        text_size = 0,              /* total text_size */
        nul_char = 0;               /* flag for +1 on first allocation */
    char buf[TITLE_MAX] = "";       /* read buffer for 'text' */
    FILE *fp = fopen (filename, "r");   /* file pointer */
    
    if (!fp)        /* validate file open for reading */
        return 0;   /* or return silently indicating no file_x or file_y */
    
    if (fgets (s->title, TITLE_MAX, fp) == 0) { /* read title */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read title from '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    len = strlen (s->title);                /* get title length */
    if (len && s->title[len - 1] == '\n')   /* check last char is '\n' */
        s->title[--len] = 0;                /* overwrite with nul-character */
    else {  /* handle error if line too long */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: title too long, filename '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (fgets (s->file_x, PATH_MAX, fp) == 0) { /* same for file_x */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read file_x from '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    len = strlen (s->file_x);
    if (len && s->file_x[len - 1] == '\n')
        s->file_x[--len] = 0;
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file_x too long, filename '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (fgets (s->file_y, PATH_MAX, fp) == 0) { /* same for file_y */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read file_y from '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    len = strlen (s->file_y);
    if (len && s->file_y[len - 1] == '\n')
        s->file_y[--len] = 0;
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file_y too long, filename '%s'.\n",
                filename);
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (buf, TITLE_MAX, fp)) {    /* read text in TITLE_MAX chunks */
        len = strlen (buf);
        if (len && buf[len - 1] == '\n')    /* check for '\n' */
            buf[len - 1] = ' ';             /* overwrite with ' ' for concat */
        if (text_size == 0)
            nul_char = 1;       /* account for space for '\0' when empty, and  */
        else                    /* use a flag to set new block to empty-string */
            nul_char = 0;
        void *tmp = realloc (s->text, text_size + len + nul_char); /* allocate */
        if (!tmp) {         /* validate realloc succeeded */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc failed, filename '%s'.\n",
                    filename);
            break;
        }
        s->text = tmp;          /* assign new block to s->text */
        if (nul_char)           /* if first concatenation */
            *(s)->text = 0;     /* initialize s->text to empty-string */
        strcat (s->text, buf);  /* concatenate buf with s->text */
        text_size += (len + 1); /* update text_size total */
    }
    
    fclose (fp);                /* close file */
    
    return 1;
}
```

With this, you will need to design a way to work through all `file_x` and `file_y` filenames. As mentioned above, this likely lends itself to a recursive function, or you can work your way down the `file_x` tree and circle back and pick up all the `file_y` additions. Note, you need to account for the new addition of `story` each time either `file_x` or `file_y` are followed.

Below is a short example that follows through all `file_x` additions and comes back and follow through **only the 1st** `file_y` branch. It is intended to shown you how to handle the calling and filling from both a `file_x` and `file_y` rather than write the final code for you. If you add the following above the `read_file` function, you will have a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h> /* for PATH_MAX */

enum { STORY_MAX = 12, TITLE_MAX = 1024 };

typedef struct 
{
    char title[TITLE_MAX],
        file_x[PATH_MAX],
        file_y[PATH_MAX],
        *text; 

} story;

int read_file (story *s, char *filename);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = 0, storycnt = 0;
    story stories[STORY_MAX] = {{ .title = "" }};
    char *filename = argv[1];

    /* read all file_x filenames */
    while (n < STORY_MAX && read_file (&stories[n], filename)) {
        filename = stories[n++].file_x;
    }
    storycnt = n;   /* current story count of all file_x */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < storycnt; i++)  /* find all file_y files */
        while (n < STORY_MAX && read_file (&stories[n], stories[i].file_y)) {
            filename = stories[i++].file_y;
            n++;
        }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output stories content */
        printf ("\ntitle : %s\nfile_x: %s\nfile_y: %s\ntext  : %s\n", 
                stories[i].title, stories[i].file_x, 
                stories[i].file_y, stories[i].text);
        free (stories[i].text);     /* don't forget to free memory */
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat file_1.txt
File 1
file_8.txt
file_25.txt
Text: "this is some example text, lenght is unknown
so i will have to use  malloc and realloc to
dynamicaly store it."

$ cat file_8.txt
file_8


This is the text from file 8. Not much,
just some text.

$ cat file_25.txt
file_25


This is the text from file 25. Not much,
just some text.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdstories file_1.txt

title : File 1
file_x: file_8.txt
file_y: file_25.txt
text  : Text: "this is some example text, lenght is unknown so i will 
        have to use  malloc and realloc to dynamicaly store it."

title : file_8
file_x:
file_y:
text  : This is the text from file 8. Not much, just some text.

title : file_25
file_x:
file_y:
text  : This is the text from file 25. Not much, just some text.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/rdstories file_1.txt
==9488== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9488== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9488== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9488== Command: ./bin/rdstories file_1.txt
==9488==

title : File 1
file_x: file_8.txt
file_y: file_25.txt
text  : Text: "this is some example text, lenght is unknown so i will 
        have to use  malloc and realloc to dynamicaly store it."

title : file_8
file_x:
file_y:
text  : This is the text from file 8. Not much, just some text.

title : file_25
file_x:
file_y:
text  : This is the text from file 25. Not much, just some text.
==9488==
==9488== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9488==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9488==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 13 frees, 3,353 bytes allocated
==9488==
==9488== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9488==
==9488== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9488== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: A binary tree would be a good solution. Though I still believe a recursive function that descends the `file_x` branch until `file_x` is empty and then recurses the `file_y` branch on the way out would work as well. Even with a btree, the challenge is still "*How do I traverse both `file_x` and `file_y` branches for every file?*" You can handle the `file_x` branch as above, but then you need to move to the first `fils_y` and follow the `file_x` branch again, then the next `file_y` and follow the `file_x` branch again until you exhaust all files (see the pattern)?

Comment: Give me a bit to get a bit of real-world work done and I'll revisit the code and see if I can't add a few more pointers.

Comment: i omitted important part of my taks ( i didnt think it was important for this part) . After user runs program (` /.ass Chapter_1.txt`) i have to print the first file in stdout (so with printf) and then user can type in choice` A` or `B` ( which are `file_x` and `file_y`) and then i output corresponding file and so on. So as i understand now, i have to make binary tree with where each structure(ex. chapter 1) holds **reference** to option A and B  ( `file_y` and f`ile_x`). I implemented binary tree in addition to your example.

Comment: My code for storing structures in binary tree is not finished but i have made basics. Would you have time to check my code? This is very important for me to finish and i appreciate  any help.